# How to style a <li> with a nested <div> with a specific class?

Tags: html, css

I need to apply custom styles to a list item with a nested `<div>` container with a specific class.

This div is not the first child element of `<li>`. I only know that it is nested somewhere inside `<li>`.

I tried this option (below), and it works with `<div>`, but for some reason, it doesn't work with `<li>`.

```css
ul{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   gap: 20px
}


li > .item-wide{
  
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Some text </li>
  <li> Some text </li>
  <li> Some text </li>
  <li> <div class="other"><div class="item-wide">Some text</div></div> </li>
  <li> Some text </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second selector. There shouldn't be that paren.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Could you please explain, what typo?

Comment: You should have `li > .item-wide`, not `li > .item-wide)`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes oh... thank you! :) If you'll add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Sorry, no, it still doesn't work

Comment: @DarrylNoakes As I wrote in the text - I need to check if there is a div with this class among children of li. In the case of nesting it doesn't work. I updated the code, please check.

Comment: Most likely it's because in your updated example, you've now nested _item-wide_ inside another div. The _>_ selector is for *direct* descendants. Remove the _other_ div and it should work. If you want it to apply to _item_wide_ no matter how deep it is, don't include the '>' in your selector.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes That's the problem - I can't remove it from my actual code. That's why I need to check if there is a div with this class somewhere among children of li, not as a first child.

Comment: [`>` - Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I need to check if there is a div with such a name inside, but not necessarily as a first child. Is there a way to do it using other selectors?

Comment: So are you trying to select the child, or the `li` containing it? Can you add new rulesets to the CSS?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Can you please reopen the question? I updated the code to fit my request, which I described in the description from the beginning "This div is not the first child element of <li>, so I need to check if it is nested inside, among other things."

Comment: [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I need to select <li> that has <div> with a specific class. But this <div> is not the first child. It can be nested several levels deep. I only know that it is inside this <li>

Comment: @imhvost I tried it, but as far as I see it checks if there are tags inside tags, but not checking classes. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: `li:has(.item-wide) { display: none; }`

Comment: @imhvost If the question will be reopened (I requested it), and you will add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just glad to help

Comment: @Rumata Just for clarity, I did not close the question. I was waiting before doing anything till I knew for certain what you were trying to do.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I understand, no worries, thank you for your help and fast response!